# In CPython what happen to a mutex when its owning thread is "killed"?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, mutex

As the title stated, I have a question regarding threads and mutex in CPython.
So my program use multiple threads and one of those threads is a "controller" which is responsible
of monitoring the other threads.

When I detect that one thread is not actualizing its timestamp at the beginning of its main loop then I marked it as not running and try to "delete" it.

This is what the controller do in this case:

```py
self.__thread_set_state(thread_id=self.job_thread_main.ident, running=False)
del self.job_thread_main
```

And then I start a new thread to "restart" the execution of the corresponding target code

```py
self.job_thread_main = threading.Thread(target=self.jobd_main)
self.job_thread_main.start()
```

But it seems that the new thread do not enter its main loop because the timestamp is not updated. Before the main loop there is some code executed which will try to acquire a mutex.

May this be possible that the previous thread always own the mutex ?

Even if its not an ideal solution (refactoring the actual code is in discussion but it will take time) is there any way to ensure that a thread is killed and more importantly that the mutexes it owned are released and if not released how to release those mutexes ?

Comment: How do you call these functions? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so  I can test your code out? It enables me to debug your problem.

Comment: IDK specifically about Python, but in many environments, if a thread dies while holding a mutex, the mutex remains locked for the rest of the process lifetime. There generally is no safe way for one thread to kill another.